# How do I add data then JOIN tables in DJango

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of players that I would like to gather stats in 3 separate categories. (Rushing, Passing and Receiving).

Every week a player gets new stats for each category.

What I'd like to be able to do is list the top 5 players for each category ordered by who ever has the most yards for that particular statistic. I'm not quite sure how to set up the query(s) in my `views.py` file or if I need to do anything within my template file in django.

Here's what my models look like:

```
class Player(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "First Name"
        )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Last Name"
        )
    position = models.CharField(
        max_length = 2,
        choices = (('QB', 'QB',), ('RB', 'RB',), ('WR', 'WR',), ),
        blank = True
        )
    team = models.CharField(
        max_length = 30,
        choices = (('Dallas', 'Dallas',), ('New York', 'New York',), ('Tampa Bay', 'Tampa Bay',), ),
        blank = True
        )
    number = models.CharField(
        max_length = 3,
        blank = True
        )

class PlayerStat(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)

    week_num = models.CharField(
        max_length = 10,
        choices = (('1', 'Sep 2nd',), ('2', 'Sep 9th',), ('3', 'Sep 16th',),('4', 'Sep 23rd',), ('5', 'Sep 30th',), ('6', 'Nov 2nd',),('7', 'Nov 7th',), ('8', 'Nov 14th',), ('9', 'Nov 21st',),('10', 'Nov 28th',), ('11', 'Dec 4th',), ('12', 'Dec 11th',), ),
        blank = True,
        null=True
        )
    rushing_attempts = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Rushing Attempts",
        blank=True
        )
    rushing_yards = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Rushing Yards",
        blank=True
        )
    rushing_touchdowns = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Rushing Touchdowns",
        blank=True
        )
    passing_attempts = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Passing Attempts",
        blank=True
        )
    passing_completions = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Passing Completions",
        blank=True
        )
    passing_yards = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Passing Yards",
        blank=True
        )
    passing_touchdowns = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Passing Touchdowns",
        blank=True
        )
    receptions = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Receptions",
        blank=True
        )
    receiving_yards = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Receiving Yards",
        blank=True
        )
    receiving_touchdowns = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        verbose_name = "Receiving Touchdowns",
        blank=True
        )
```

I'm a noob to python and Django so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I you have to change the model to use the [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) for the stats and then
query for each stat the top 5:

```
PlayerStat.objects.order_by('receiving_yards')[:5]
```

You can also give an order listing more than one field to order from

```
PlayerStat.objects.order_by('receiving_yards,receptions,receiving_touchdowns')[:5]
```